# Events that trigger on an HTML element's attribute change.(js)

Tags: javascript, html, events, dom

Let's say you have a slide bar

```
<input id='bar' type='range' value='50'>
```

Is there an event listener I can use that will be triggered by the value changing?
If not, can I use JavaScript to make a custom event listener?

```
document.getElementById('bar').onAttributeChange('value',function(){
    // some code.
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can listen to the `onchange` event (which will fire when you finish scrubbing) e.g. not while you drag, but when you are done.

e.g.

```
<input id="bar" type="range" value="50" onchange="...">
```

or using an eventListener:

```
document.getElementById('bar').addEventListener("change", doSomething, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the combination of `oninput()` and  `onchange()` event, something like below code.

```
<input id='bar' type='range' value='50' oninput="showVal(this.value)" onchange="showVal(this.value)" >

<script>
function showVal(newVal){
   console.log(newVal);
}
</script>
```

`oninput` is triggered when you slide the slider and `onchange` is triggered when you release the mouse.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/7gxj73yd/)